# XML/HTTP transport in CXF without SOAP

Tags: java, xml, http, cxf, xmlhttprequest

Please let me know if it is possible to send an XML as a string over a http connection and get back the response in a XML (as a String) without using any parsing mechanism?

Is it feasible in Apache CXF? or use of Streams/parsers is mandatory? Is there a configuration in Apache CXF which does this for me if I provide the content-type as text/xml?

I want to do this without using SOAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the WebClient API support in CXF.

Snippet below:

```
    WebClient client =WebClient.create(url);
    client.type("text/xml");
  client.accept("text/xml"); 
  javax.ws.rs.core.Response resp=client.post(request);
  return resp;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the JAX-RS features of Apache CXF: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs.html . If you are using Spring MVC, you can easily do this using [Controller annotations itself](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html)